# How do I compute the residuals from glmnet in r?

Tags: residuals, lasso, glmnet

I am working with `glmnet` and i would like to compute the residuals for the model with lasso penalty. I've simulated data split into training and testing set. My codes are as follows:

`lasso.glm<-glmnet(trainx,trainy,family="gaussian", alpha= 1)`
Following, I've extracted the predicted values using:

```
 pre.lasso.X<-predict( lasso.glm.final,trainx,s=best.lambda.lasso,type=c("link"))
```

Now how can I get the residuals for the above model?

Comment: There is no mention of residuals in the manual, have you tried `resid(lasso.glm)`?

Comment: Since your model is linear, the residuals are defined as the observed values minus predicted values, so subtract the latter from the former.